# Angular/ChromeHeadless unit tests fail on Visual Studio Online

Tags: angular, azure-devops, google-chrome-headless

I have a Angular7 application with UnitTests. I'm running them succesfully on my local machine with

```
ng test --source-map=false --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
```

But when I run the CI pipline on VisualStudioOnline (AzureDevOps), the same command just returns with

```
2018-11-06T10:50:29.3023236Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
```

The only (small) difference is the node/npm version
Local: Node 8.11.1 / NPM 6.1.0
VSOnline: Node 8.12.0 / NPM 6.4.1

Comment: 2018-11-06T10:50:29.3022723Z ##[debug]rm -rf D:\a\1\npm
2018-11-06T10:50:29.3022814Z ##[debug]removing directory
2018-11-06T10:50:29.3022880Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-11-06T10:50:29.3023236Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2018-11-06T10:50:29.3023447Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2018-11-06T10:50:29.3034171Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2018-11-06T10:50:29.3034897Z ##[section]Finishing: npm run test extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to close this issue...
Always be aware about all the console.log's in Chrome. With headless in Azure, it's not the most comfortable way to analyize this. But running the tests locally with browser support makes it easier.

Comment: "Always be aware about all the console.log's in Chrome" - did that have something to do with the solution?